# When attempting to pass an int to determine array size in an array wrapped in an object, code does not execute depending on int size?

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing, wrapper

This is my third java course and we're reviewing sorting algorithms. I am using Eclipse to compile and run my code. I have an array wrapped in a class as such:

```
    class ArrayBub
    {
private long[] a;                 // ref to array a
private int nElems;               // number of data items

public ArrayBub(int max)          // constructor 
  {
  a = new long[max];                 // create the array
  nElems = 0;                        // no items yet
  }

public void insert(long value)    // put element into array
  {
  a[nElems] = value;             // insert it
  nElems++;                      // increment size
  } 

    ... 

public void display()             // displays array contents
  {
  for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)       // for each element,
     System.out.print(a[j] + " ");  // display it
  System.out.println("");
  }
// there are other methods not listed here
```

The assignment is to pass an integer of at least 10000 into the constructor to create an array of this size. I am to observe how long it takes to insert this many values into each array index, along with how long it takes to bubble sort this array. The bubble sort method is not listed above.

My main method so far looks like this:

```
class BubbleSortApp
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  int maxSize = 10000;    // array size
  ArrayBub arr; // reference to array

  long n = 0;
  arr = new ArrayBub(maxSize);  // create the array

  for (int j=0; j < maxSize; j++) {
      n = (long) ((java.lang.Math.random()) * (maxSize - 1) );
      arr.insert(n);
  }

  arr.display(); // display items

  System.out.print("\n Done.");

  // arr.bubbleSort();             // bubble sort them

 // arr.display();                // display them again

  }  // end main()
}  // end class BubbleSortApp
```

I have the bubblesort and second display methods commented out so i can just test inserting the large amount of elements.

My issue is that when attempting to pass maxSize = 10000 into the constructor and then execute, the array printout does not display and instead the "Done." prompt simply appears.  I've tried altering maxSize to a smaller int, say 1000, which seems to work. When i try increasing maxSize, however, it seems to work arbitrarily. For some values the array displays fine, for other it doesn't. I've had instances where the same maxSize value causes the array printout to display on one run and not display on another.

I'm pretty puzzled. It seems to have something to do with the value of maxSize, but Eclipse is not showing any compile or runtime errors and I've already tried putting everything into try/catch blocks to weed anything else out.

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/tchBkA).

Comment: There's no apparent reason to me why this wouldn't behave as expected.

Comment: Huh...Maybe an issue with Eclipse then?

Comment: @MattAngelucci it's possible this is a problem with long lines on the console. Try changing print to println and see if that works.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? It will help you to understand if your code get executed or not.

Comment: @kutschkem Ah hah, that worked. Definitely wouldn't have thought to do that. I compiled and ran it both in cmd and Eclipse and it seems to be running fine now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open bug with long lines not being displayed:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23406

Try to either replace print with println or insert newline characters every now and then.